# How to display the dynamic values in cucumber extent report

Tags: selenium, cucumber, extent

i want to show the dynamic values in cucumber extent report

Ex:

**Feature file**

Given enter the userid as <"userid">

And enter the current time as <"currenttime">

**Examples:**

|userid | currenttime|

|10002  | today      |

**Definition file:**

```
@And("^enter the current time as (.*)")
public void currenttime(String arg1) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");  
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date)); 
    if (arg1 == "today") {
        driver.findElement(By.id("period")).sendKeys(formatter.format(date));
    }
}
```

**In cucumber Extent Report:** it shows "today" only instead of dynamic value (current time= "07:18")

please guide me..

Comment: Did you meant "Extent" report?  If so, you should tag that.  Also, you show no code at all, only your feature file.  "today" is passed as a parameter and likely your code is specifically converting that into the current date, but Gherkin will simply pass "today" to the step, not do the conversion for you, so the report likewise will not convert the feature line.

Comment: i have updated the definition file,

Comment: There is no shortcut here, I'm afraid, since you are almost certainly using the feature of Extent Reports to automatically interface with Cucumber.  The alternative is to write the Extent Report without that automatic option, following the examples of the BDD section of their documentation and manually pass the steps (after you determine the current time).  It requires more code on your part, but it will work.   It's how I have to do iit with JBehave since there's no automatic interface for that, only for Cucumber.